# Issue with terraform lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

This is what I'm getting when I run terraform plan, It used to work earlier with previous version, So basically concat is returning list instead of string.

```
Errors:

* At column 3, line 1: lookup: argument 2 should be type string, got type list in:

${lookup(var.az, concat("zone", count.index + 1))}
```

I'm using compiled version of terraform

```
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.7.0-dev (854c9bd488dfdb12303ec47e42d6de8fc17e40a5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (always a good idea with Terraform before upgrading versions as they are constantly developing and frequently make non-backwards-compatible changes.)

> 0.7 (Unreleased)
>
> BACKWARDS INCOMPATIBILITIES / NOTES:
>
> [...]
>
> - The concat() interpolation function can no longer be used to join strings.
>
> [...]
>
> - You now access the values of maps using the syntax var.map["key"] or
>     the lookup function instead of var.map.key.