# Terraform Error : Invalid dot index found

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform version 0.11.8
and tried this POC https://github.com/salizzar/terraform-aws-docker
when I do terraform init it throws following error.
I am novice to use terraform. googled a lot and tried reffering terraform module registry to get rid of this error,but in vain.

Can someone please run this POC and point what needs to be changed?

https://github.com/salizzar/terraform-aws-docker/blob/master/main.tf

```
**ERROR :**

[root@localhost test]# terraform init
There are some problems with the configuration, described below.

The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.

Error: Error loading /home/tottally/main.tf: Invalid dot index found: 'var.aws_security_group.sg_count'. Values in maps and lists can be referenced using square bracket indexing, like: 'var.mymap["key"]' or 'var.mylist[1]'. in:

${var.aws_security_group.sg_count}
```

Comment: I found a reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375252/issue-with-terraform-lookup it seems that concat function is obsolete in terraform  but still I am stuck at replacing it

Comment: one of the failed try is  getting rid of concat in main.tf and replacing it like this :name        = "terraform_security_group_${lookup(var.aws_security_group, "sg_[count.index]_name")}"

Answer (score 1):

I think Terraform is not happy with this line:

```
count = "${var.aws_security_group.sg_count}"
```

Instead of using this double dot notation, try using square bracket indexing, as Terraform itself suggests in the error message:

```
count = "${var.aws_security_group[sg_count]}"
```

By the way, this repo is really old, you can find better and up-to-date examples in the public Terraform registry.